# Convert unix timestamp to datatime sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, unix-timestamp

I have query like this

```
select * from my_tabel where created_at >= 1655546400000
```

I want to give this query to the end-user and the ceraetd_at field in the database is Unix timestamp and he doesn't know Unix timestamp so he should be able to change it to custom DateTime. I want to change it to this query because this query is readable for end-user

```
select * from my_tabel where created_at >= "2022-06-18 10:00:00"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=Convert+unix+timestamp+to+date+sql+query+site:stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Unless you have `set quoted_identifier off` in effect (on Microsoft SQL Server the default is `on`) then `"2022-06-18 12:20:00"` will be interpreted as an object identifier. Do you have a column named `2022-06-18 12:20:00` in your table?

Comment: Unix timestamp 1655546400000 is  2022-06-18 10:00:00. Are you sure?

Comment: @Serg this is only sample.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I want to give this query to end user and he don't know unix timestam. I want to change query readable for end user. I updated my post

Comment: @HojjatShaygani can you please share your table schema and a few dummy data?

Answer (score 2):

I have found this very helpful, you can try it. After converting you can use the value however you want.

```
DECLARE @UnixDate BIGINT = 1655546400000
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(ms, CAST(RIGHT(@UnixDate,3) AS SMALLINT), 
       DATEADD(s, @UnixDate / 1000, '1970-01-01')) AS DATETIME2(3))
```

More details about [DATEADD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function.

After the update of your question, What I have understood after reading your question is, that your user wants to compare date with `ceraetd_at` field, as UNIX time does not give much details about regular date format, that's you want to convert the `ceraetd_at`, so that they can compare or run their query.

So for doing that you can do like below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_tabel 
WHERE (CAST(DATEADD(ms, CAST(RIGHT(created_at,3) AS SMALLINT), 
        DATEADD(s, created_at / 1000, '1970-01-01')) as DATETIME2(3))  
       >= '2022-06-18')
```